# How to implement dependency injection via constructor - Python

Tags: python, dependency-injection

I have rewritten a C# dependency inversion example in Python. I have created an interface called `CalculatorOperation` and trying to implement dependency injection via the `Calculator` constructor. The problem is when I run the code, it returns `None`. If I change `self.calc_op = CalculatorOperation()` to `self.calc_op = Addition()`, it returns the correct value of 15.

```
class CalculatorOperation():
    def calculate(self, num_1, num_2):
        pass


class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, calc_op):
        self.calc_op = CalculatorOperation()

    def solve(self, num_1, num_2):
        return self.calc_op.calculate(num_1, num_2)


class Addition(CalculatorOperation):
    def calculate(self, num_1, num_2):
        return num_1 + num_2


class Subtraction(CalculatorOperation):
    def calculate(self, num_1, num_2):
        return num_1 - num_2


def main():
    addition = Calculator(Addition())
    print(addition.solve(10, 5))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() # None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass in the object that you created in main (don't re-do the initialization from within the `__init__` method), like so:

```
class Calculator:
    def __init__(self, calc_op):
        self.calc_op = calc_op
```